# Linux interface for all tagged vlans, excluding untagged traffic

Tags: networking, interface, vlan

I know that I can create a VLAN interface by simply creating a new interface and assign the vlan number to the parent interface name with a dot, eg. eth0.5 for vlan 5 on the eth0 NIC.

I wonder if it is possible to separate the traffic on a NIC to one interface with all VLANs, e.g. all tagged packets and another one handling only untagged packets?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Are you asking if it's possible or how to do it (or both)?

Comment: Sorry. If it is possible, I ask for both. Otherwise only if it is possible.